# Populate taxonomy page with blocks of content from other taxonomy vocabularies

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

I would like to create a page that holds two blocks of content. One would be a view-block showing a list from content type A and the other a view-block showing a list from content type B. The caveat is that the content type lists show information that has been specifically tagged with a specific location and the page itself is auto-populated based on taxonomy for that location.

(For example, mysite.com/states/oregon would display blog posts for Oregon as well as resources for Oregon.)

The two content types have their own taxonomy vocabulary for a state list content A taxonomy and content B taxonomy and a third state taxonomy list for the state pages, taxonomy C. I think this might be a problem...

- Do I need to use one taxonomy vocabulary for each of these content types in order to create a taxonomy page that can populate two blocks of content tagged by the taxonomy terms; (this is less ideal for my situation at the moment)
- **or** is there a way I can build a view block using contextual filters to call forth the different vocabularies in order to populate tagged content for each content's taxonomy vocabulary? If I can accomplish the latter, then I'm hoping I can just assign the block to the content area of the taxonomy C page as per usual.

Bonus: I'm already using a taxonomy view to control the appearance and behavior of my taxonomy pages.

Comment: Have you tried extracting the term name from the path and [looking up the term by name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7.x) for the vocabulary A, and looking it up again by name for vocabulary B? Even though the tids are different in vocab A vs B, as long as the state names are identical in both vocabularies I think you should be able to pull this off.